# Error configuring PowerPivot 2012 on SharePoint 2013. New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance - The PowerPivot System Service does not exist in the farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powerpivot, sql-server-2012

Hi I'm hoping that someone can help me out here.  I have a Multi-server dev farm that I am unable to provision PowerPivot correctly.  It worked fine on the standalone farm.  Any help would be appreciated

It keeps failing on the "Register Powerpivot System Service on Local Server"

SharePoint 2013 is patched to SP1 (15.0.4569.1000)

Installed Analysis Services SQL 2012 SP1 as a named instance on my Application Server.  SQL is patched to CU5 (trying to get PowerView configured as well).  Am able to load the PP named instance in SQL mgmt studio.

My Setup account is SYSADMIN on the SQL instance, and Local Admin on all servers (1 WFE, 1APP)

I've removed and reinstalled a few times, but not really getting anywhere.  The spPowerPivot.msi version I am using is 2012 SP2.

This is the PowerShell output if I run that command on its own:

```
PS C:\Users\sharepointsetup> New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance -Provision:$true
New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance : The PowerPivot System Service does not
exist in the farm.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance -Provision:$true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Analy...ServiceInstance:
   NewPowerPivotMidTierServiceInstance) [New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance]
  , GeminiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.PowerShell.NewPowerPivotMidTierServiceInstance
```

I set logging to VerboseEx to see if there's more detail but there isn't and SQL trace wasnt very helpful.  Here's the ULS for the corresponding command from PowerShell:

> 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11 PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint
>   Foundation Usage Infrastructure ai6qo VerboseEx Updating the
>   CorrelationManager Activity id to the correlation id
>   'c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef'.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Monitoring aeap2
>   Verbose Set diagnostics context correlationid
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef, trace level Medium,
>   isDevdashboardenabled False c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef
>   09/23/2014 16:04:20.11 PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint
>   Foundation Logging Correlation Data 77a3 Verbose Starting correlation.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Unified Logging
>   Service cn4f Verbose Trace level override is set to 50.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Monitoring ahgom
>   VerboseEx Constructing SPMemoryData
>   [cbf3d7d3-e4ea-4986-bab3-4fd22bb0e884]... StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMemoryData..ctor()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext.SetContext(Guid
>   correlationId, ULSTraceLevel traceLevel, Boolean
>   isDevDashBoardEnabled)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext..ctor(Guid
>   correlationId, ULSTraceLevel traceLevel, Boolean
>   isDevDashBoardEnabled)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPDiagnosticsSessionManager.StartCmdletDiagnostics(SPCmdlet
>   cmdlet, Action1 initCorrelationCallback)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.SPCmdletDiagnostics..ctor(SPCmdlet
>   cmdlet)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.BeginProcessing()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean
>   incomingStream)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input,
>   CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[]
>   pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections,
>   FunctionContext funcContext)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction5.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0
>   arg0)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action1
>   clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase
>   commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Monitoring ahgoq
>   VerboseEx Starting SPMemoryData [cbf3d7d3-e4ea-4986-bab3-4fd22bb0e884]
>   gathering... StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMemoryData.Start()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMemoryData..ctor()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext.SetContext(Guid
>   correlationId, ULSTraceLevel traceLevel, Boolean
>   isDevDashBoardEnabled)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext..ctor(Guid
>   correlationId, ULSTraceLevel traceLevel, Boolean
>   isDevDashBoardEnabled)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPDiagnosticsSessionManager.StartCmdletDiagnostics(SPCmdlet
>   cmdlet, Action1 initCorrelationCallback)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.SPCmdletDiagnostics..ctor(SPCmdlet
>   cmdlet)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.BeginProcessing()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean
>   incomingStream)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input,
>   CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[]
>   pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections,
>   FunctionContext funcContext)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction5.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0
>   arg0)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action1
>   clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase
>   commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation PowerShell 6tf0
>   Medium Entering BeginProcessing Method of
>   New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation PowerShell 6tf0
>   Medium Leaving BeginProcessing Method of
>   New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation PowerShell 6tf0
>   Medium Entering ProcessRecord Method of
>   New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Unified Logging
>   Service 854l Verbose refreshing throttle cache for
>   AnalysisServicesDiagnostics, a064583c-080b-4c49-bbfb-7a99554b579e
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 PowerPivot Service Unknown 97 Verbose
>   Attempting to retrieve MidTierService
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation PowerShell 6tf2
>   High Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.GeminiException: The
>   PowerPivot System Service does not exist in the farm.     at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.MidTierService.GetService()     at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.PowerShell.NewPowerPivotMidTierServiceInstance.InternalValidate()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.11
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation PowerShell 91ux
>   High Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object 
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.PowerShell.NewPowerPivotMidTierServiceInstance
>   Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.14
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Usage
>   Infrastructure ai6qo VerboseEx Updating the CorrelationManager
>   Activity id to the correlation id
>   'c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef'.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.14
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Monitoring ahgon
>   VerboseEx Disposing SPMemoryData
>   [cbf3d7d3-e4ea-4986-bab3-4fd22bb0e884]... StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMemoryData.Dispose()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext.Dispose(Boolean
>   disposing)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext.Dispose()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.EndProcessing()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase
>   commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input,
>   CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[]
>   pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections,
>   FunctionContext funcContext)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction5.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0
>   arg0)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action1
>   clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase
>   commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.15
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Monitoring ahgor
>   VerboseEx Stopping SPMemoryData [cbf3d7d3-e4ea-4986-bab3-4fd22bb0e884]
>   gathering... StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMemoryData.Stop()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMemoryData.Dispose()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext.Dispose(Boolean
>   disposing)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPAsyncThreadDiagnosticsContext.Dispose()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.EndProcessing()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase
>   commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input,
>   CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[]
>   pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections,
>   FunctionContext funcContext)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction5.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0
>   arg0)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action1
>   clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase
>   commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.15
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Logging
>   Correlation Data 77a3 Verbose Ending correlation.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef 09/23/2014 16:04:20.15
>   PowerShell.exe (0x47E4) 0x30B4 SharePoint Foundation Unified Logging
>   Service cn4g Verbose Trace level override is turned off.
>   c05ec940-ce33-4ef1-92b5-6f61a2ec37ef

Answer (score 0):

Fixed errors like: 
-Configure Local Service Instances,

- -Register PowerPivot System Services on local server
- -Cannot create the service instances because the parent service doesnot exist
- -Prerequisites check for execution filed. Farm is not in a valid state. in powerpivot by doing

Before installing or trying to install powerpivot in sharepoint 2013--

create secure store service key for powerpivot -- by going to CentralAdmin>secure store service>New and give name to target application ID-Powerpivotunattendedaccount, display name- Power pivot unattended account data refresh, contact email address, select none for target application name and click next.
In the 1st field name type- username and field type a windows username, 2nd field type as -  password and field type windows password and click next and provide admin account username name.
Now go to download spPowerPivot installer [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35577) and install the installer and open the power pivot configuration tool and follow the instructions.

or if you are using sql server 2012 standard version after installing the sp installer go to tools in the sql server 2012 and click configure powerpivot and follow instructions.

Comment: That didnt work, any other ideas?